# Linking a UITableView to NSMutableArray

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, datasource

This isn't a "please help me debug my code" message. I actually have it working, but want a deeper understanding of *how* it works!

I have a view-based xCode application. On my main view, I have a UITableView and I've set the delegate and dataSource to File's Owner.

In my .h file for the Main ViewController, in the @interface section, I declare an NSMutableArray which will contain a list of custom objects.

In the @interface declaration, I include the protocols UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

Later, after a few button taps, my code parses an XML file from a server and inserts objects into the NSMutableArray. I added code to the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, which gets called as it should, and when I call the reloadData method for my UITableView, the table gets populated with the results parsed from my XML!

Pretty cool, but I'd like to understand how this happens; a better understanding will be useful to me in the future.

I never explicitly tie my NSMutableArray to that UITableView. Why does cellForRowAtIndexPath get invoked when an object is added to the array? How is it connected? Is it because the NSMutableArray is declared in the @interface block which has the protocols that I mentioned above? If I had two UITableViews on my .XIB how would the code know which NSMutableArray should be mapped to which UITableView? (Or is that something I should strive to avoid?) Even if I only have on UITableView on the XIB, if I have two NSMutableArrays, will I have to be concerned with them somehow tangling up my UITableView?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArray --- in your case it is the data to be displayed in table view. When display has to happen Table view ask for the data using data source.

*How they are connected* -- Data source ask for the data there is not other explicit connection.

*How to handle 2 table view* -- Ideal approach is have different data source object for each table view, each object will have its own NSMutableArray of data.

*1 table view and 2 NSMutableArray* -- It is left to the data source implementation, depending on your need you can display data of any NSMutableArray objects.

*Why does cellForRowAtIndexPath get invoked when an object is added to the array?* -- you might be calling view reloadData

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call [tableView reloadData]; your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and numberOfRowsInSection are called.

Its because of the UITableViewDataSource protocol. There's no connection between NSMutableArray and UITableView.

When a new object is added to the array, after that [tableView reloadData]; will be called. Hence, now the cellForRowAtIndexPath method will be called for the array which will be having a count increased by 1.

Hope this wud help. :)